# How to prevent TypeError when working with Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I am working with the titanic dataset, after splitting data into test and train set, TypeError is always returned when i find the mean of the train and test set but not the overall dataset.

```
data2 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Hash/titanic.csv', usecols=['age', 'fare', 'survived'])
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    data[['age', 'fare']],  # predictors
    data['survived'],  # target
    test_size=0.3,  # percentage of obs in test set
    random_state=0)  # seed to ensure reproducibility
median = X_train['age'].median() #Returns 28
```

But when I try the mean i get an error

```
mean = X_train['age'].mean()
```

I get this error

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Comment: it seems the error is not in the mean computation but somewhere in your code where you create a string. please post whole related code with the line with the error

Comment: also you read the data in data2 variable but you use data variable after that, is this a typo?

Comment: Thanks Nikos, that was the problem actually. Instead of data2 i was using data. Thanks, it works fine now.